# Generating an incremental version when building Delphi applications

Tags: delphi, build, version

I am looking for a way to incorporate an incremental version number into a large delphi application. We have automated the Delphi build process by using a script to call MSBUILD with the appropriate parameters for each Delphi project within the entire application. Ideally, I want to be able to generate the next version number at the beginning of the build script and have that included in each .EXE and .BPL that is created by the build.

Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this without spending $$$ on a third party build tool?

BTW we are using Delphi XE2.

Thank You

Comment: Write a script in your favourite scripting language to increment the version.  Execute it as a pre build action.

Comment: If you want to avoid spending $$$ buy a good book on Python and learn how to write the useful utility glue scripts that make such tasks easy

Comment: I write my build scripts in Delphi...

Comment: That sounds pretty labour intensive. Oranges are not the only fruit.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest to disable including the version resource information by Delphi, and include your own (central) version `.rc` script. Then write a tool/script that (re)generates this version resource script up front of the MSBuild configuration. (For an example [VERSIONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058.aspx) rc, [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows))

Comment: Thank you all. This all looks very helpful.